# Facebook ShareDialog is shown from one activity but not from another

Tags: android, facebook

I call ShareDialog by the same way from 2 activities: MainActivity and ReleaseActivity, but behavior is different: from MainActivity I share to facebook app, but from ReleaseActivity can't do that. 
Callback to catch result (for testing)

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d("Tracing", "ReleaseActivity 63 onSuccess");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("Tracing", "ReleaseActivity 68 onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.d("Tracing", "ReleaseActivity 74 onError " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Code for ShareDialog:

```
 if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        Log.d("Tracing", "ReleaseActivity 100 facebookOnClick");
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Test title")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "Test text-description")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
        Log.d("Tracing", "ReleaseActivity 110 facebookOnClick");
    }

    Log.d("Tracing", "ReleaseActivity 111 facebookOnClick end");
};
```

In both activities after pressing facebook button I see logs in ShareDialog's code, in MainActivity Facebook window pop-up, but not in ReleaseActivity.

I don't see facebook window but after pressing on facebook button I press android Overview button to see launched apps and see facebook app (with black screen), when I press on this facebook black screen it disappears.
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn0tlqhgce5za7o/fc.jpg?dl=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJyDE.jpg)

Callback show me result only in MainActivity.
Android SDK 4.14.1

Why it works in one case and doesn't work in another? What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it started to work when I wrote
`class ReleaseActivity extends BaseActivity` as MainActivity has, instead of
`class ReleaseActivity extends Activity`
BaseActivity: `class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity`.

So, classes that extend `AppCompatActivity` work with Facebook SDK, and classes that don't do that - don't work.